# defaulting datatype double to 0 if input is null

Tags: c#, forms, types

I am having a bit of difficulty setting a variable to 0 if the user doesn't enter a value into the textbox, it is making it tricky because the variable gets passed around multiple forms, if it was in the same form it would be much easier to do. My code is attached down below.

```
//in one of my input forms
//runs on button click
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TXTCustomerGrowth.Text))
{
  fm.SaveGrowth(Convert.ToDouble(TXTCustomerGrowth.Text));
  //fm is instance of class where my methods to save variables are
}

//in class
public void SaveGrowth(double value)
{
    customerGrowth = value;
}

public double GetGrowth()
{
    return customerGrowth;
}

//in the final summary form
double growth = fm.GetGrowth();
```

I have tried initially saving the variable as a string and converting to a double when i need it but it complains that it cannot convert type string to double so basically what I want to know is how I can modify that first if statement so if the textbox is null then set the variable to null (my issue being I am not sure how to do it in my situation because the variable isnt created in the input form.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention it runs fine initially but I have an edit button on the summary screen which allows you to change your values and its when they delete the growth value and leave it blank it doesnt register and keeps the growth the same as what it was.

**EDIT2:**

My edit button just brings you back to the beginning so your values you entered aren't deleted, 
when the summary button is pressed this method is called:

```
public void ShowSummary()
{
    calculatingForm.Show();
    summaryForm.UpdateForm();
    calculatingForm.Hide();
    summaryForm.Show();
}
```

and in the UpdateForm method is:

```
double growth = fm.GetGrowth();
```

Comment: Does your edit feature call `SaveGrowth`?

Comment: See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266946/1997232) regarding edits. The question is not about your first statement, it won't help if you are willing to update value from somewhere else and expecting new value to be used.

Comment: no edit just restarts the program becuase the forms are never closed, just hidden

Comment: Then if `edit` doesn't `SaveGrowth`, why do you expect `customerGrowth` to be updated? Your `edit` feature sounds like all it does is call `GetGrowth`, which at no point sets `customerGrowth` to the new value.

Comment: because the whole summary form gets updated when you show the summary is shown, its done in a method

Comment: Please show the relevant code for your edit feature.

Comment: question edited

Answer (score 0):

```
String Foo = "21"
Double bar;
if(Double.TryParse(Foo, out bar))
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Upon further attempts answer my own question here is the code answer:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TXTCustomerGrowth.Text))
{
    fm.SaveGrowth(Convert.ToDouble(TXTCustomerGrowth.Text));
}
else
{
    fm.SaveGrowth(0);
}
```